# SQL SELECT from third level table

Tags: sql

Ok I know little about SQL so bear with me...

I'm trying to see if certain values exist in a third level table and I don't know how to go about it. Here is the scenario...

I have a Accident table that holds accident information. It has 3 one-to-many child tables (Units, Occupants, NonMotorists). An each of those child tables have their own many-to-many child table (Alcohol). I need to be able to have some way of seeing if a range of values exists in a field in those Alcohol tables. Here is watered down version of what my structure for the tables looks like...

```
--tblAccident--_  
PK_AccidentNumber    

--tblAccidentUnit--  
PK_PrimaryKey  
FK_AccidentNumber  

--tblAccidentOccupant--    
PK_PrimaryKey  
FK_AccidentNumber

--tblAccidentNonMotorist--  
PK_PrimaryKey  
FK_AccidentNumber

--tblAccidentUnitAlcohol--  
PK_PrimaryKey  
FK_ForeignKey  
AlcoholValue <---- THIS IS WHAT I NEED TO SEARCH   

--tblAccidentOccupantAlcohol--  
PK_PrimaryKey  
FK_ForeignKey  
AlcoholValue <---- THIS IS WHAT I NEED TO SEARCH   

--tblAccidentNonMotoristAlcohol--  
PK_PrimaryKey  
FK_ForeignKey  
AlcoholValue <---- THIS IS WHAT I NEED TO SEARCH
```

---

I hope this makes some sense as to what i am trying to accomplish. thank you

Comment: Can you describe what rows and columns you want in your results? Have you tried anything at all? If so, can you post it?

Comment: I'm a little unclear still.  Are you saying, given a PK_AccidentNumber, what are the possible AlcoholValues in any of the three tables that have alcohol values?

Comment: Are you wanting to get all accidents by joining through to the AlcoholValue where the AlcoholValue is in some range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you just want to get info from the third level table if the range exists.

Try the query given below:

Since the database is not specified am not sure if the BETWEEN operator in your database would includes the test values.

```
SELECT  AccidentNumber, 'AccidentUnit' AS TableFound, c.PrimaryKey AS TableKeyValue
  FROM  tblAccident a INNER JOIN tblAccidentUnit b
      ON    a.AccidentNumber = b.AccidentNumber INNER JOIN tblAccidentUnitAlcohol c
        ON  b.PrimaryKey = c.ForeignKey
     AND    c.AlcoholValue BETWEEN <RANGE_START> AND <RANGE_END>
UNION       
SELECT  AccidentNumber, 'AccidentOccupant' AS TableFound, c.PrimaryKey AS TableKeyValue
  FROM  tblAccident a INNER JOIN tblAccidentOccupant b
      ON    a.AccidentNumber = b.AccidentNumber INNER JOIN tblAccidentOccupantAlcohol c
        ON  b.PrimaryKey = c.ForeignKey
     AND    c.AlcoholValue BETWEEN <RANGE_START> AND <RANGE_END>
UNION
SELECT  AccidentNumber, 'AccidentNonMotorist' AS TableFound, c.PrimaryKey AS TableKeyValue
  FROM  tblAccident a INNER JOIN tblAccidentNonMotorist b
      ON    a.AccidentNumber = b.AccidentNumber INNER JOIN tblAccidentNonMotoristAlcohol c
        ON  b.PrimaryKey = c.ForeignKey
     AND    c.AlcoholValue BETWEEN <RANGE_START> AND <RANGE_END>
```

Comment: USe UNION ALL as there is no need to distinct. It willbe much faster.